# Excel - Include Row in Sum Based on Comparison to Following Row

Tags: excel

### Paging All Excel Wizards,

I am trying to see if there is a way to have a one-line SUMIF or something similar to sum up the following criteria in an Excel spreadsheet:

**Sum the values of Column C if**

1. If Column A = "Chizzle"
2. AND If Column B is >= Column B of the next row

Sample Data:

```
  A      B     C  
 Type  Level Value
__________________
Chizzle  1     23 
Chizzle  2     10 
Bobbles  3    1.5 
Bobbles  3    2.6 
Chizzle  2    5.5 <- Should Be counted
Cobbles  2      1 
Chizzle  1    3.3 <- Should Be counted
```

I have tried using something like this:

```
=SUMIFS(C1:C1000,A1:A1000,"Chizzle", B1:B1000, ">=" & B2:B1001 )
```

Unfortunately the B2:B1001 part isn't working and it is selecting all values.

If there is a way to do this with a one line calculation, without having to add an additional column? That would be awesome but I'm not sure if it is possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$8="Chizzle")*($B$2:$B$8>=$B$3:$B$9)*($C$2:$C$8))
```

[image]

Comment: You are way too fast.

Comment: Thank you so much for this Scott, could you walk me through how it is working exactly?

Comment: @Chizzle The sumproduct() is iterating through the ranges.  Each part is a True/False Boolean.  Since True returns 1 and false returns 0, Both the first parts have to be True for it to return the value in C; `1*1*Value of C=Value of C`

Comment: Thank you, I think I was close, perhaps I needed to anchor the row numbers in my ranges?